# Making double spaced Chapter title in latex using titlesec

Tags: spacing, chapters, titlesec, books

I am beginning to write my first draft of my dissertation, and my institution requires that my chapter titles be centered and have the following format.

--larger vertical space--

'Chapter' Chapter number

--vertical space--

Chapter title

--larger vertical space--

I'm trying to use the titlesec package to do this, but I'm having some trouble understanding why this is not working.

In my preamble this is what I have for the chapter title format

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\filcenter\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{Chapter \thechapter}{1em}{\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{0pt}
```

and later in the document I have this,

```
\chapter{Introduction}
```

but this is the output.

[image: chapter title]

How can accomplish this desired format? And if possible, is there a link that can be provided for how using the titlesec package on this site? I'm referring to a pdf I have that is supposed to detail how to use the package, but it provides very few examples and I'm also quite new to LaTex.

Thank you

Comment: Use the `display` style in the first place. If you do not want the word ‘Chapter’, don't write it in the code. And you might be interested in the *Advanced interface* section of the documentation.

Comment: I do want 'Chapter', not sure why you think I don't want it.

Comment: Oh! Just because you didn't mention it in the specifications, and it is also a possible layout, especially with very big chapter numbers. B.t.w. for vetical spaces, it might be interesting to use `ex` as a unit (it is the height of the x letter in the current font).

Comment: Oh ok. I can see how that can be confusing. But yeah basically I'm just looking to have a double space 'Chapter' chapter Number then chapter Title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a starting point. In `\titlespacing`, I used the shorter notation `*12`, &c., which means a verical spacing of 12ex, with some stretchability/schrinkability if necessary. Adjust the values to your needs:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\filcenter\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{Chapter \thechapter}{1em}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{*12}{*20}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]